# Cannot implicitly convert type float to int. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a zombie spawn at a random spawnpoint out of an array of spawnpoints. 
Using unity game engine
it says "cannot implicitly convert type float to int An explicit conversion exists(are you missing a cast?)"

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class sown : MonoBehaviour
{
    System.Random rnd = new System.Random();
    public GameObject[] zomz = new GameObject[1];
    public Transform[] spawns = new Transform[9];
    public GameObject regzom;
    int unonumero = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        foreach (GameObject x in zomz)
        {
            zomz[unonumero] = Instantiate(regzom, spawns[Mathf.Round(Random.Range(0f, 10f))]);
            unonumero++;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost done, the error is trying to say that you are using a float instead of an int.

Array index can only be integers, in your line:

```
zomz[unonumero] = Instantiate(regzom, spawns[Mathf.Round(Random.Range(0f, 10f))]);
```

You are using `Mathf.Round(Random.Range(0f, 10f))` to get the random and then round it and that is a wise choice, so you have a random float number like 2.4f rounded to 2.0f, the problem is that it still a float, not an integer.

Matfh has a cool Round method that gives you an integer, you can use this `Mathf.RoundToInt()`, like:

```
zomz[unonumero] = Instantiate(regzom, spawns[Mathf.RoundToInt(Random.Range(0f, 10f))]);
```

I hope its clear  :)

Comment: Thank you so much I am so shocked that I would get responses so much, this is my 3rd game and I haven't finished any so your help is certainly aprectiated

Answer (score 1):

`Mathf.Found` returns a float, [proof](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Round.html). That float is then being used as an index for spawns[]. Only ints are allowed for indexing.

```
void Start()
{
    foreach (GameObject x in zomz)
    {
        zomz[unonumero] = Instantiate(regzom, spawns[(int)Mathf.Round(Random.Range(0f, 10f))]);
        unonumero++;
    }
}
```

Edit:
Marco Elizondo's answer is better. Use Mathf.RoundToInt instead.